# .NET 6 GRPC on raspberry pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, grpc, .net-5, .net-6.0

**Background -** i am writing a project managing sort of an enclosed area dispatching automated vehicle using .NET 6 and raspberry pi, the Pi received instructions using Wi-Fi, manages the motion system using a PLC (Programmable Logic Controller), basically, works fine.
I am using 32Bit Raspebian (updated)
I wanted to implement a "technician's UI" using GRPC, something i have done several times on window machines, i use the "gRpc.Core" nugget (+ dependencies..), create a server:

```
grpcServer = new Server {
    Services = { ACTechService.BindService(grpcHandler) },
    Ports = { new ServerPort("192.168...", 50051, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
}
```

works find on windows (using a test client i wrote)
When i move the code (that otherwise works!) to the RPi and run it i get:

```
GRPC server start failed, exception:: System.InvalidOperationException: Unsupported architecture "Unknown".
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.GetArchitectureString()
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.GetNativeLibraryFilename()
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethodsUsingExplicitLoad()
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethods()
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension..ctor()
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.Get()
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMethods.Get()
    at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.GrpcNativeInit()
    at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment..ctor()
    at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.AddRef()
    at Grpc.Core.Server..ctor(IEnumerable`1 options)
    at Grpc.Core.Server..ctor()
    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Projects\AirTouch\CarMk2.5\Tries\GRPCMyServer\Program.cs:line 10
```

I google and understood the problem is that the gRPC is not pure .NET, there is an underlying native library that is not implemented on the Raspberry Pi

Microsoft **has a pure NET library** called "Grpc.AspNetCore" i couldn't figure out how to use it in a console application :-(

**And the question:** bottom line, looking for a grpc server package that will work on Arm32 architecture, namely the RPi, either using the microsoft version (if its good) or any other alternative
thanks

Comment: grpc.AspNetCore is intended to be used from .net core application which hosts a server or starts a client and talks to the server. gRPC is all about report procedure calls. You can start a console application which acts as self host or use .net core supplied web server such as Kestrel. Here is an example - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Maybe this github repo helps: [C# GRPC for Arm (x32 / x64)](https://github.com/xevilmaxx/grpc_arm_csharp)

Comment: ARM32 is not supported by Grpc.Core by default. You'd need to bring in a custom-build version of the grpc_csharp_ext native component in order to make things work on 32-bit Raspberry pi (and of course it would be officially unsupported).  You should be able the run a grpc-dotnet server (ASP.NET Core based) on raspberry pi, there should be plenty of examples out there on how to run a console app with grpc-dotnet server in it (even the Greeter server in the grpc/grpc-dotnet repository is actually a console app).